# Creating Classic UI SharePoint with Office 365

Tags: office-365

I'm using my Office 365 Business account to create a SharePoint team site for our company.  Using the Office 365 admin center tools is it possible to still create the site with the Classic UI experience?  I've seen posts on using Windows PowerShell for changing the site to classic after the fact.  However, not being that experienced with PowerShell, I was looking for something more direct in the Admin Center that allows the creation of the site with a Classic UI from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create your site with classic experience.

Go to  :

1. Admin portal
2. Admin centers
3. SharePoint
4. Settings

Scroll down and you will get **Site Creation** like the image below :

[image]